# Javascript save , erase and reload input value

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my Script. I want to do the following steps in this order:
1. Save the text in the input field.
2. Delete all text in the input field.
3. Reload the same text that was deleted before in the input field.

The problem with my script is that the `ug()`- function writes  `undefined` in my textbox instead of the string that should be stored in `var exput`. The `alert(exput)` however shows me the correct content.
Help would be very much appreciated. And I'm sure there is better ways to do that, I'm quite new to this stuff.

HTML

```
<textarea  id="a" style="width: 320px; height: 200px;"></textarea>
<input type="checkbox" id="remember" onclick="merker();deleter();ug()" />
```

Javascript

```
function merker() {
    var merkzeug = document.getElementById('a').value;
    ug(merkzeug);
};

function deleter() {
      if(document.getElementById('remember').checked == true)
      {
        document.getElementById('a').value = "";
      }
      else {document.getElementById('a').value = "";
      }
    };

function ug(exput) {
    alert(exput);
    document.getElementById('a').value = exput;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is calling `merker(); deleter(); ug();` in the onclick event, but `ug()` is already called by `merker()`. You should be doing this instead:

```js
function merker() {
    var merkzeug = document.getElementById('a').value;
    deleter();
    ug(merkzeug);
};

function deleter() {
      if(document.getElementById('remember').checked == true)
      {
        document.getElementById('a').value = "";
      }
      else {document.getElementById('a').value = "";
      }
    };

function ug(exput) {
    alert(exput);
    document.getElementById('a').value = exput;
};
```

```html
<textarea  id="a" style="width: 320px; height: 200px;"></textarea>
<input type="checkbox" id="remember" onclick="merker();" />
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!! Just to clarify. I got "undefined" back because I called the function ug() twice? Once in the onclick event and then in merker()?

Answer (score 0):

I changed Your Javascript:

```
function merker() {
  merkzeug = document.getElementById('a').value;//global variable without var
  ug();//why You use it here? I think only for test. So delete it after.
};

function deleter() {
  if(document.getElementById('remember').checked == true)
  {
    document.getElementById('a').value = "";
  }
  else {document.getElementById('a').value = "";
  }
};

function ug() {
  alert(merkzeug);
  document.getElementById('a').value =merkzeug;
};
```

Problems with your code:

- method **ug** was used with argument and without argument ( i changed to without )
- to restore deleted value it must be saved to some variable, i saved to global **merkzeug** variable - this is not good practice but sufficient in this case
- next i used **merkzeug** to restore value in textarea in ug() function
- i do not know why You using ug() two times? maybe delete one of them is good thing to do.

In plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/fc6iJBL80KcNSpaBd0s9?p=info

Answer (score 0):

problem is: you pass undefined variable in the last ug function:

you do: merker(value) -> ug(value); delete(); ug(/*nothing*/);

or you set your merkzeung variable global or it will never be re-inserted in your imput:

```
var merkzeug = null;
function merker() {
    merkzeug = document.getElementById('a').value;
    ug(merkzeug);
};

function deleter() {
      if(document.getElementById('remember').checked == true)
      {
        document.getElementById('a').value = "";
      }
      else {document.getElementById('a').value = "";
      }
    };

function ug(exput) {
    if (typeof exput === 'undefined') exput = merkzeung;
    alert(exput);
    document.getElementById('a').value = exput;
};
```